# C# 3.5 Reading Excel files

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, import-from-excel

I have a strange behavior when i try to read an XML worksheet using this code :

```
string CONNEC_STRING = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=2;\"";
            string fullFilePath = @"C:\Tmp\TestFile.xls";
            using (OleDbConnection objCon = new OleDbConnection(string.Format(CONNEC_STRING, fullFilePath)))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cm = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [MYCELLSRANGE]", objCon))
                using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cm))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    objCon.Open();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    objCon.Close();
                }
            }
```

If the Excel file is closed, I receive the error 'External table is not in the expected format.'
When I open the file, if I execute the above code, it works fine and I can read data contained in MYCELLSRANGE.
So, has anyone any idea about this problem ?
Thanks for answers.

Comment: Have you tried different values for IMEX?

Answer (score 2):

I believe its because the Jet Engine uses the Excel app to interpret the file.  I ran into this issue once myself.  When you use the Excel.dll reference and you interpret the Excel file from that you have to create a new Application instance to read the file.  Jet just does this very thing to get the data.  I suggest using that code instead.

- [C# Corner example of how to Import Excel to a ListView](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mgold/howtooepnandreadanexcelspreadsheetinalistviewin.net11282005034134am/howtooepnandreadanexcelspreadsheetinalistviewin.net.aspx)
- [C# Corner example of how to Create an Excel Worksheet in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ggaganesh/CreateExcelSheet12012005015333AM/CreateExcelSheet.aspx)
- [MSDN users discussing the same topic](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/isvvba/thread/a30a353d-7f0a-4ab3-a6ea-b127416d604c)

If you would like further assistance, let me know.  I have successfully done this in VB.NET in various applications of mine.